# MS SQL Server CAST to int returns unexpected output

Tags: sql-server, unicode, utf-8, casting, ucs2

OS type:  Windows
SQL Server: 2017
Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

I have a stored procedure as below

```
USE [test]
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[output_test]   
    @output nvarchar(250)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT CAST(@output AS int)
END
```

Input to the procedure: '1234'
I use MultiByteToWideChar() function to convert from UTF8 to UCS2 before passing to the procedure.
The output of the MultiByteToWideChar() function is '1111'
But when the procedure is executed, I got error as below

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1234.' to data type int.
```

It is noted that an extra '.' is appended at the end.

But When we just retrieved the data without cast (SELECT) it has correct value as 1234

I have aallocated (strlen+1)*sizeof(SQLWCHAR) =>(4+1)*2 = 10 bytes to store the resulted wide char string, which is output from MultiByteToWideChar function. Here additional 2 bytes are allocated for null termination.

However, if that additional 2 bytes for null termination is not added then the procedure works fine.

1. Could anyone help me in understanding why the extra bytes causes the problem (though it is 0, it results in '.') ?
2. Whether there is any limitation with CAST to int when using Unicode characters ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope - we can't help you debug code that you did not post. The issue here is not related (directly, anyways) to sql server. It is related to the code you wrote to execute this procedure. The problem lies with how you pass the parameter (confusingly named `@output1` suggesting that it is an output parameter).

Comment: The procedure is provided in the description. I am not sure about what you mean here "confusingly named @output1 suggesting that it is an output parameter"

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
alter PROCEDURE Test (@YesNo VARCHAR(5) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @YesNo = 1

END
GO


DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(5)

EXEC Test @YesNo = @Result OUTPUT

SELECT @Result
```

Comment: Thank you Eben. Can you please clarify what is the issue ? I am more interested in understanding the Root cause.